# Rotating Android bootup screen

Tags: boot, nexus-7, boot-animation

I have a Nexus 7 (2nd generation) on Android 6.0. I am able to rotate and fix the screen on landscape using `adb shell content`. I am also able to adjust screen dimensions and resolution using `adb shell wm`.

Now, the only thing I need to really do is figure out a way to rotate the entire device to actually be permanently in landscape mode so that when it reboots the Android logo and everything is in landscape.

Is there any way to do this? My device is rooted already if that helps.

Comment: Boot process and boot logo are device specific. There is no common way to change it.

Comment: Seconding Robert's comment, you have to modify and rotate the boot logo animation manually, and this depends on the device model.

Comment: Any idea how to rotate the boot logo and boot animation on the Nexus 7 2nd generation?